# WordPress login page just refreshes after successful login

Tags: php, wordpress

Background:
I have a WordPress website that lives in a Google Cloud-based load balanced environment, and as I work through getting CI/CD setup I elected to isolate one of the servers so that my team could properly run through isolated testing.  Since the website is on a regular domain ([www.mybusiness.com](http://www.mybusiness.com)), I created a duplicate database from our production DB and pointed the isolated server at this new test database.  From there, I updated both the 'siteurl' and 'home' values with the isolated server's IP address in my wp_options table, and from there I can access my isolated WordPress site by simply using the URL.  However, this is where things get frustrating: the login page simply refreshes after a successful login attempt, while blatantly incorrect login attempts with invalid credentials properly return user login error messages.

After countless hours searching the Internet, Stack, and elsewhere, I've found that the most common solutions are either:

1. Clear your browser's cookies / cache.
2. Try logging in with completely different devices (other cell phones, laptops) to confirm it's not a device or local browser-cache issue.
3. Deactivate and test each plugin,
4. Confirm your 'siteurl' and 'home' values are correct.
5. Test your .htaccess file to confirm that's not the problem.
6. Clear your user's WordPress 'session_tokens' meta_key value.
7. Revert back to an older / default WordPress theme to confirm if it's a theme problem
8. Run WordPress's built-in DB repair tool.
9. Create new WordPress salts and swap them in inside the wp-config.php file.
10. Enable the 'WP_DEBUG' constant to see if anything in the error logs pops up.
11. Test non-HTTPS versions of 'siteurl' and 'home'.

After trying all of the above, nothing seems to work: reverting to an older theme (twentynineteen) still presents the same login page refresh issue, and I've gone through every plugin on the server to see if deactivating one or all of them creates a solution - none seem to be the root cause.  Error, mysql, and auth logs are also maddeningly clean.

Interestingly, if I add a trailing slash to my IP address-based 'home' and 'siteurl' value, from 'https://11.11.11.11' to 'https://11.11.11.11/' I do successfully get to the correct internal landing page (https://11.11.11.11/landing-page/) - *however* it just displays a 404 with the basic white screen.

Current WordPress version: 5.4.7

This leaves me with a few questions:

- Is this a file permissions issue somewhere?  Are there any key WordPress files in which permissions could create this effect?
- Would Apache or anything VPC be in play here?  I checked out our Apache .conf files, but those don't seem to be the suspect.
- Should we look into a WordPress upgrade knowing we're a bit behind with 5.4.7?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: You said the login page just refreshes - is that landing page this: https://site-ip-here/wp-admin?  Later you say when you add a slash to the IP, you successfully get to the correct internal landing page - I'm confused how this is supposed to work.

Can you share the Apache VHost code for the site?

Comment: Have you checked your htaccess files?

Comment: Yes, .htaccess has been tested with default WP versions; no luck there.  @Kaboodleschmitt: The landing page is a custom internal template like site-ip-here/landing-page, and not the /wp-admin page.

Comment: Can you share the VHost code from apache?